# CI tools for static checking of environment variables definition

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

For some security reasons, all of our projects are not allowed to define the environment variables in `Dockerfile` ,`entrypoint.sh` (for starting the application). Currently, we have to review each merge request manually to ensure this rule, I wonder if there is some ci tool to automate this work to make life easier, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GitLab comes with [container scanning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/) by default, but I don't believe it's possible to achieve this level of granularity. This might be possible in a pipeline [using Trivy for scanning](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.18.3/integrations/gitlab-ci/) in conjunction with [custom Trivy policies](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.27.1/docs/misconfiguration/custom/) to detect misconfigurations in Dockerfiles. It will take some trial and error to detect and write custom policies, but I believe it can be done.